# How to track demographic info of child (under 18 years old) website users?

Tags: google-analytics, demographics

I'm used to using Google Analytics and Hitwise to get demographic info (particularly age) of a websites' users. Neither of these track users under 18. I know it's unlikely for a range of [reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children's_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act), but are there any tools that do? Even to get a sense of the overall proportion of users who may be under 18 would be useful.

Failing that, what techniques would you recommend for getting a rough guide to the trajectory of child visitor numbers? I'm currently looking at upstream traffic in Hitwise, and tracking % of of users who've also visited key sites aimed at children. Vague I know, but better than nothing.

Ideally, I'd introduce user accounts, mailing list signup or another method of data capture to collect this info first hand, but before I do that...

Comment: What purpose are you tracking minors for?

Comment: I'm working on sites for a couple of children's content/product brands - videos, minigames etc based on eg. cartoon characters. Trying to get a sense of whether a change in content strategy attracts more of the consumers themselves, rather than parents researching.

Comment: Looks like you're out of luck. From the [Google Analytics Demographics and Interest Reports Page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819950?hl=en): "Google does not include age data below 18."

Comment: Thanks - my question is "I know Google Analytics doesn't track this, are there any alternative tools or techniques I can use instead?

Comment: I searched and never found any... I asked earlier because I thought you wanted to keep minors out.  The only way I can think of off the top of my head is to include a checkbox etc that says something like Are You Under 18, during account signup, but then you'd also need Did you ask your parents permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any mainstream tracking platforms that will track minors. The only few solutions I could think of are:

1) Make users sign up for something and ask for their age. Something Like a user profile.

2) Do surveys on your site that ask that question. You can do a standard survey or you can do something like pop-up lightboxes with a question.

Be aware that there are **A LOT** of laws that prevent you from gathering info on minors. Laws such as Children’s Privacy Policy (COPPA) - http://www.ftc.gov/enforcement/rules/rulemaking-regulatory-reform-proceedings/childrens-online-privacy-protection-rule